# Is is possible to run visual studio code within the browser (i.e., as a web app, without electron)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since VS Code is Javascript based, it seems like one should be able to launch it in the browser as a web app.  However, I can't seem to find anyone doing that?

I was able to launch the Monaco Editor this way, but I'm looking for the complete Visual Studio Code application, with support for extensions.  Anyone know if/how this would be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it is not possible to run VS Code in a browser.

Comment: @pvg That;s not true of course, and likely also not true in 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I am looking for:  https://coder.com/